How move rocket logs to file?
I tried to find an easy way to transfer logs from the console to a file. I can't find a suitable option for me on the Internet. I run 2 threads at once, one of which should receive output from the user, but at the same time, the logs from Raketa interfere with convenient use. After all, when someone interacts with the Web server, the input gets lost. Tell me how I could transfer them to a file?
Code example:
#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {
    // Creating thread
    thread::spawn(|| {
        let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();

        // launching rocket
        rt.block_on(async {
            // Rocket start
            let _start = web_page::rocket().launch().await;
        });
    });

    // Another code
    start()
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Since Rocket's log output is based on the log crate and defaults to using env_logger, you can initialize the logging before starting Rocket to customize the log output.
For example, using fern as the implementation:
cargo.toml
chrono = "0.4.38"
log = "0.4"
fern = "0.7.0"

main.rs
use std::fs::OpenOptions;

use chrono::Local;
use fern::Dispatch;

// init log
fn setup_logging() -> Result<(), fern::InitError> {
    let log_file = OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        .append(true)
        .open("output.log")?;

    Dispatch::new()
        .format(|out, message, record| {
            out.finish(format_args!(
                "[{}][{}][{}] {}",
                Local::now().format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                record.level(),
                record.target(),
                message
            ))
        })
        .level(log::LevelFilter::Info)
        // Do not send to standard output.
        // .chain(std::io::stdout())
        .chain(log_file)
        .apply()?; // Apply the logging configuration
    Ok(())
}

#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {
    setup_logging().expect("Failed to initialize logging");

    // Creating thread
    thread::spawn(|| {
        let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();

        // launching rocket
        rt.block_on(async {
            // Rocket start
            let _start = web_page::rocket().launch().await;
        });
    });

    // Another code
    start()
}


When I try use your method I can't compile the code: the "?" operator cannot be applied to type "impl std::future::Future<Output = Result<tokio::fs::File, std::io::Error>>" bellow .open("output.log")?;

@Yuniversia I just took a look, and it seems that OpenOptions might be imported from rocket. You may need to import it using std::fs::OpenOptions.

I found my mistake. I imported OpenOption from tokio, what caused the error.

But here's the problem. The log file contains strange symbols that are impossible to read.

@Yuniversia This issue arises because Rocket outputs to the terminal with colors, which is implemented using ANSI escape codes. When this output is redirected to a file, it results in unrecognized characters appearing in the log.

I tried to find a quick solution. Maybe disable it in rocket.toml but I don't see such an option. Should this problem be solved somehow using fern?

@Yuniversia You can disable colors and emoji by setting the ROCKET_CLI_COLORS environment variable to 0 or false when running a Rocket binary: ROCKET_CLI_COLORS=false cargo run.

Thanks for your help. I was able to set up logs in a separate file and fix the color issue. I added Cli_colors = false in Rocket.toml
